# Hook up new thermostat

Tags: thermostat, air-conditioning, heat-pump, heat

Top brown picture is my old thermostat white is the new one , do I have it wired correct? On out side unit we have replaced motor, fuses, compassator ,cc contactor ,relay . We have a heat pump. But the fan still will not work to blow into the house [image][image]

Comment: Is that new thermostat capable of handing a heat pump with emergency heat?  Not all of them can do that...  That jumper between Y and W looks wrong, and I'm not sure you should have a wire going to R and Rc (those two commonly have a jumper).  The picture of the new thermostat could be better - less blur and better colors.

Comment: Yes it can handle heat pump,  and jumper between y and w was in the instructions, x which is the brown wire was hooked up in old thermostat but don't have an x in the new one

Comment: Link to the instruction manual would help or at least the model of the new thermostat and make of the old one.  And again, just because it supports "heat pump" doesn't mean it supports emergency/aux heat (notice the X in aux heat).

Comment: New thermostat is a Honeywell rth221b, the old one is Rheem lr1620 , I think or t874r1442

Comment: The old one has an em heat option but they jumped it to just use regular heat  from what I could tell

Comment: That Honeywell model is NOT compatible with emergency/aux heat at all so you wouldn't be able to use it for that.  Do you have electric or gas heat to use as a backup if the heat pump can't handle the cold?

Comment: No just the heat pump, we have replaced a lot of parts but the fan itself is still not turning so that's why we're trying a new thermostat

Comment: The only other part we have not replaced is the delayed timer

Comment: If you connect the R wire and the G wire and touch nothing else, the fan should come on for a simple test.  I can't tell what wire you have connected to Rc.

Comment: That is the brown wire in the rc slot that was connected to the x in the old thermostat and I'll try just having the r and g connect and see what it does

Comment: I can't find the exact instructions for your thermostat, but normally there is a jumper between R and Rc and the red wire connects to either (since the jumper connects them).  If the thermostat expect power on Rc, that would explain it not working.

Comment: Ok well I took out every thing except r and g and fan still not running...

Comment: You may still have something wrong then.  if you physically touch the R and G wires together, the fan should come on when the unit is powered on.  Measuring with a volt meter, there should be 24v from red to green.

Answer (score 0):

These pictures seem to be programmer baseplates,programmer plugs into,if so the new base plate connections will differ.It has to be assertained by careful circuit comparison that all switching is observed,connection will be dependant on   the control devices ,lettering of connections is normally used to assist following the instructions.You have taken on a tricky job,with instructions it is possible to get it right,experts sometimes have trouble.Check to see if the new programmer will plug into the old baseplate.Careful not to damage it,hope this helps Steve uk engineer.